# Norm defined on derivative is not a norm

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Let $C^{1}[0,1] = \{ x \in C[0,1] : x' \in C[0,1]\}$. Let $\|x\|_{1} := \|x\|_{\infty} + \|x'\|_{\infty}$. *Show that $\|x'\|_{\infty}$ is not a norm.* Note $\|x'\|_{\infty} = \max_{t\in[0,1]}|x'(t)|$.

My thoughts:

A norm must have the property that $\|x\| = 0 \iff x = 0$. Since $x' \neq 0$ may be zero on the closed interval $[0,1]$ this cannot be a norm since it may be the case $\|x'\|_{\infty} = 0$ when $x' \neq 0$.

However, this seems too simplistic of an explanation.

Comment: Better: any constant function on $[0,1]$ has zero derivative.

Comment: Shouldn't the quote be: $\| x\|_1$ is not a norm? (Though, the notation  $\| x\|_1$ is not the most clever, with respect to the standard Taxicab norm)

Comment: That's how it appears in the text. In this case, it seems $\|x\|_{1}$ is a norm but not $\|x'\|_{\infty}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the correct idea, but you're expressing it in a bad way.

A constant function has zero derivative, but it is not necessarily the zero function.

The other properties of a norm *do* hold, so  this is the only reason why this function is not a norm. It is a *seminorm*.

---

Note that you are actually computing the sup-norm of the derivative. The function
$$
x\mapsto\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|x(t)|=\|x\|_\infty
$$
*is* a norm on $C[0,1]$. However, the map $x\mapsto x'$ from $C^1[0,1]\to C[0,1]$ is surjective, but not injective.

Comment: I see...so $\|x'\|_{\infty}$ is not explicitly requesting the norm of the derivative? Since $x = c$, $c \in \mathbb{R}$, then $x' = 0$.

Comment: @clocktower It's just a symbol (and a handy one), just it doesn't define a norm on $C^1[0,1]$. On the other hand, $\|x\|=\|x\|_\infty+\|x'\|_\infty$ *does* define a norm.